# ConTeXt: Frame a Sentence

Tags: formatting, context, backgrounds

How can I frame a single sentence in a paragraph when the sentence may wrap around to become several lines long? Just like `\color` but to also provide background color, frame, styling, and so forth. The idea is to provide a formatting for inline code that unlike `\type` ignores input whitespace.

- `\color` works fine but only sets the foreground color
- `\framed` doesn't wrap
- `\type` wraps but only sets the foreground color. Also unlike `\color` doesn't ignore input whitespace.
- `\start...stoptextbackground` forces a new block even when used as `left=` and `right=` arguments to `\setuptype`.
- `\framed` doesn't actually wrap the input to `\type` when used like:

  ```
  \setuptype[command=\mtc]
  \define[1]\mtc{%
      \dontleavehmode{\framed[frame=on,
                              background=color,
                              background-color=orange,
                             ]{#1}}}
  ```

This is what I mean by "ignore input whitespace":

```
\setuptype[color=red,style=\tf]
\starttext
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been \type{the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries}, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been \color[red]{the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries}, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\stoptext
```

[image: Clarify "ignore input whitespace". Notice the unintentional whitespace in the first paragraph.]

Though I guess it doesn't matter since I can do this, based on the accepted answer:

```
\definetextbackground
  [mtcframed]
  [frame=on,
   framecolor=black,
   backgroundcolor=orange,
   rulethickness=1pt,
   location=text,
  ]

\starttext
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been \starttextbackground[mtcframed]the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries\stoptextbackground, but also the leap into
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\stoptext
```

[image: Using <code>\starttextbackground</code> without <code>\type</code>, inline within a block]

And then define a new macro for consistency with other style commands:

```
\define[1]\mtc{\starttextbackground[mtcframed]#1\stoptextbackground}
```

*Edit:*

There are minor overfull box issues in English as well. To be fair this is related only to the use of monotype fonts. Unfortunately it is very noticeable as the text spills out of the frame. How can I fix this? For example, with either approach:

```
\unprotect
\defineinterfacevariable{collapse}{collapse}
\setvalue{\??typingspace\v!collapse}{\def\obeyedspace{\unskip\space}}
\protect

\definetextbackground
  [mtcframed]
  [frame=on,
   framecolor=black,
   backgroundcolor=orange,
   rulethickness=1pt,
   location=text,
  ]

\define[1]\mtcA{\starttextbackground[mtcframed]\tt#1\stoptextbackground}

\definetype[mtcB]
    [space=collapse,
     left={\starttextbackground[mtcframed]},
     right={\stoptextbackground},
    ]
```

[image: Demonstrate how, with either approach, text overflows the frame]

Also is there any reason to prefer `\definetype[...][space=collapse...]` over `define[1]\mtc{...}`? The former is interesting and useful but seems overly complex.

Comment: Use `\definetype[mtc][space=stretch]` to get the regular interword glue.  I have also updated my answer.

Comment: For me it doesn't spill out the frame.  Are you using the latest beta?

Comment: The other problem is that hyphenation is by default switched off for teletype fonts, because you usually use those for code and hyphenation doesn't make sense there.

Comment: Hyphenation is disabled for `\type`, but it doesn't seem by default switched off for teletype fonts. If I typeset my example paragraph using `\tt` I actually have more hyphenation than without. As for `\type` setting `lines=hyphenated` doesn't influence the overflow.

Comment: I'm using the ConTeXt standalone beta 2018.10.18.

Comment: Teletype fonts usually do not have kerning (and hyphenation is usually switched off).  Furthermore spaces might not be strechable/shrinkable.  This lack of flexibility leads to bad breaks.  Normally this is not an issue because no sane person would typeset the text body in teletype.  On the other hand teletype fonts *have* to be that rigid when used to display code, because indentation carries semantic meaning (sometimes it is even syntactically required, e.g. in Python).  If your code is too long to fit in a single line in text, give it an extra paragraph and break manually.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a real-world example to your question.  That would make it a lot easier to find a proper solution.  All cases discussed so far are rather artificial.  No one would ever display a full sentence as code.

Comment: I don't have a concrete use-case; rather I'm trying to find out whats possible. I vaguely intend something similar to github's inline-code markup, for when standard style alternatives aren't appropriate: a cross between background-highlight and inline code. For example, log excerpts, filesystem paths, textual highlights (only the last doesn't require teletype).

Comment: To be precise I'm now just interested in fixing the overflow (irrespective of font style) out of the colored background.

Comment: You'd have to use `align=tolerant` (or even `verytolerant`) but that only works on whole paragraphs, not just a few lines of a paragraph.

Comment: Neither `align=verytolerant` nor `tolerance=verytolerant` (with `start...stopparagraph`) have any effect. A bit disappointing but that's that, I guess. I assume you considered solutions that didn't involve `\type`?

Comment: In teletype font, the space has a fixed width with no stretch and shrink.  I updated my answer to use a flexible space.  For me, there are no more overful boxes now.

Comment: Thanks, though I have to admit that non-monospace teletype text is pretty disconcerting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\start...\stoptextbackground` is the correct thing to do but you have to set `location=text`.  To collapse interword spaces, I define a new spacing method `collapse` and use it in `\setuptype`.  I also add a little bit of stretch and shrink to the interword space for better linebreaking.

```
% The original version, which only collapses interword spaces.
%\unprotect
%\defineinterfacevariable{collapse}{collapse}
%\setvalue{\??typingspace\v!collapse}{\def\obeyedspace{\unskip\space}}
%\protect

% The updated version, which in addition adds stretch and shrink
\unprotect
\defineinterfacevariable{collapse}{collapse}
\setvalue
  {\??typingspace\v!collapse}%
  {\def\obeyedspace{\unskip
      \hskip\interwordspace
      plus .5\interwordspace
      minus .5\interwordspace\relax}}
\protect

\definetype
  [mtc]
  [left={\starttextbackground[mtcframed]},
   right={\stoptextbackground},
   space=collapse]

\definetextbackground
  [mtcframed]
  [frame=on,
   framecolor=black,
   backgroundcolor=orange,
   rulethickness=1pt,
   location=text]

\starttext

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
industry.  Lorem Ipsum has been \mtc{the industry's standard dummy
  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries}, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Great answer. LaTeX (and the contributors here) keep to amaze me.

Comment: Why use `\type`? Isn't it better to simply set `style=mono`

Comment: @Aditya In this case yes, but OP wants to use this to typeset code.